# IE 11 Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "getAttribute"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

В IE v.11 вылезает ошибка при триггере функции по клику на рейтинг (5 звезд), причем, иногда, клик по рейтингу не отдает никакой ошибки. Пыталась выявить закономерность и найти какую-то зацепку: ошибка всегда вылезает рандомно.

> Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "getAttribute"

```js
filter: {
    "ID": assertGetIdNotName ?
        function(id) {
            id = id.replace(rbackslash, "");
            return function (elem ) {
                /**
                 * Начало проблемы
                 */
                return elem.getAttribute("id") === id;
                /**
                 * Конец проблемы
                 */
            };
        } :
        function(id) {
            id = id . replace(rbackslash, "");
            return function (elem ) {
                var node = typeofelem.getAttributeNode !== strundefined && elem.getAttributeNode("id");
                return node && node.value === id;
            };
        },
    }
```

Данный метод должен поддерживаться IE, но тем не менее вылезает ошибка.

[image: Кроссбраузерность метода getAttribute]

Comment: все зависит от того, чем является `elem` в момент вызова этого метода

Comment: что-нибудь с svg?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, как раз svg разметка используется

Comment: @Qwertiy ^^^^^^

Comment: @Grundy, ну я угадал. Надо какие-нибудь полифиллы подключать и/или дебажить. Что тут ещё сказать можно. Ну может `pointer-events: none` поможет, если не требуется элементы внутри svg различать.